# how to convert python string binary representation to json

Tags: javascript, python, image, vue.js, binaryfiles

i am trying to convert this file reference string to JSON

```
"{'file_reference':
b'\\x04~\\x9eaR\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x05e\\xeb;~6t\\x035\\x95=\\xf4D\\xb4\\xfc\\xb4\\x95>\\x03\\x10\\xd4'}"
```

using

```
JSON.parse()
```

but when parsing to JSON am getting this error

> Unexpected token 'b', ..."ference": b"\x04~\x9"... is not valid JSON

also I am getting

> Expected double-quoted property name in JSON error

and also

how to I solve this?

Comment: That is not valid JSON, so `JSON.parse()` will definitely fail (as you've seen). Your Python code is surely capable of producing legitimate JSON, but whatever it is doing is not that.

Comment: if that string was the value of a variable `foo` then you can get it as a dictionary via `foo_dict = ast.literal_eval(foo)`

Comment: What result do you want to see with that input?

Comment: the object is stored as  a string but i am converting to json using javascript. 

i just want it to be converted to a format that can be stored in json